# Math book with horsemen tessellation cover

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a math text I read when I was younger that had MC Escher's 'horsemen' tessellation on the cover. One of the Horsemen was colored red and the others in grey and white. As I remember, the book covered a wide variety of topics. The only two chapters in it that I remember are conics and billiards.

If anyone knows the title of this book, I would greatly appreciate if you could help me remember this gem!

[image: MC Escher's Horsemen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Mathematics, a Human Endeavor, by Harold Jacobs. The edition that has the red horseman is the second edition.  Your memory is correct, the front cover has a single red, the rest beige (but I am not a reliable reporter of colour) and white. The back cover has horsemen also, none red.

The third edition front cover has another Escher tessellation, birds. I believe there have been a number of editions since then.  I only have the two editions mentioned.

Comment: @cowchee Found [this](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Human-Endeavor-Textbook-Subject/dp/0716713268) and [this](http://newyork.olx.com/mathematics-a-human-endeavor-edition-2-iid-168502648) googling André's answer.